# Running gcloud from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I need to adjust the settings of a Google Cloud Run container twice a day. (specifically: adjusting the number of min-instances to balance performance and cost)

So I am trying to write a shell script and then execute that script at specific times each day (Mac OS environment).

In Terminal this command works just fine for me:

```
gcloud run services update [my-containers-name-here] --min-instances 0
```

but when I try to run it in a shell script (allow-idle.command), this fails:

```
do shell script "gcloud run services update [my-containers-name-here] --min-instances 0"
```

The error I receive when I try to run the shell script is

> command not found: gcloud

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Install gcloud in your PATH.

Comment: When you install the CLI (gcloud) you probably installed the program either 1) relative to your user account in the file system or 2) the environment variable PATH is only set up for the CLI for your user account. Find where the CLI is installed (use there ** where gcloud** command) and set up the environment variable PATh for CRON. I don't have a Mac so I cannot double-check which method is correct.

Comment: One challenge with your approach is that, if your Mac is offline, the Cloud Run service won't be updated. Unfortunately, the alternatives aren't as straightforward. You could (!) run either a small VM with cron or use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to securely ping e.g. a Cloud Function either using the Cloud Run admin API to update the service's min|max instances.

Comment: Bingo.  Thank you JohnHanley and Cyrus.  Gcloud was not permanently installed in PATH.

Comment: I permanently installed gcloud by running  .../google-cloud-sdk/install.sh which added the following to my .zshrc file:# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi